# PrimeNG, Menubar items to the right side

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-menu

I have a PrimeNG Menubar component, I want my items in the right side, they are currently on the left side, how could I align them to the right? In this case I want to align all of them to the right, not just a specific one

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
</p-menubar>
```

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  items: MenuItem[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Solicitudes (5)',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-clock'
      },
      {
        label: 'FrankHesse',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Perfil',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user'
          },
          {
            label: 'Salir',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-power-off'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

}
```

I tried modifying the `styles.scss` file in the following way

```
#mercadeoucab .p-menuitem{
    float: right !important;
}
```

mercadeoucab is the ID of my body in the index.html file, however it didn't do anything, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to override PrimeNG CSS this way:

```
::ng-deep .p-menubar {
  height: 50px;

  p-menubarsub {
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
  }
}
```

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menubar-demo-52vxyv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Comment: isn't ::ng-deep deprecated? I'm using Angular 10 and it's not working for me

Comment: Do you use CSS or SASS? If you don't want to use `ng::deep` you can set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component (like I edited in my StackBlitz).

Comment: I'm ussing SCSS

Comment: alright, the `ViewEncapsulation` was the thing that was missing

Comment: With this CSS, when the menu bar is collapsed the sub-menus appears missplaced

Answer (score 1):

For me, I did it with the following CSS:

```css
p-menubarsub{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

This will align all the items to the right, and will work well when collapsed. However, when collapsed, the sandwich menu will still show to the left, and if you also want it to go to the right, then add the following css:

```css
 a.p-menubar-button{
    order: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`p-menubar` is a flex container, that means you can use this css to extend one of it's items (e.g. middle one):

```css
    p-menubarsub {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
```